# How does data travel in a butterfly network?

Tags: graphs, parallel-computing

I'm trying to learn how communication works in a butterfly network.

[image]

The following is a butterfly network of order 3. I'm given the following description:

> Each processor is connected to an output switch in rank 0 and to an input switch in rank k (in this case 3). In other words the switch in column j and rank 0 gets its input message from processor j and the switch in column j and rank k delivers its message to processor j. Messages only travel in one direction - towards switches of increasing rank.

I'm having trouble interpreting what it means by the input and output switches. At first I thought the messages were traveling from bottom to top, but the last statement makes it sound like it's traveling from top to bottom. Is the processor j mentioned found on top in rank 0? I'm trying to grasp how messages travel from one processor to another.

Answer (score 1):

The description you were given is indeed phrased in a confusing way.  I suspect they're talking about messages travelling from top to bottom.

I suspect by "output switch" they might mean "output from the processor" (input to the butterfly network), which *is* pretty confusing.  That explanation could have been phrased better.

Butterfly networks are described in many places.  You might want to find another description of butterfly networks and read that.